# Laravel download file from google drive

Tags: php, laravel, storage, google-client

I want to download some mixed files from google drive using my Laravel App but for exp Images download correctly, but Docs file comes empty

**Provider:**

```
\Storage::extend("googleConsole", function($app, $config) {
        $client = new \Google_Client;
        $client->setClientId($config['clientId']);
        $client->setClientSecret($config['clientSecret']);
        $client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']);
        
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $config['folderId']);
        return new Filesystem($adapter);
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
$response = Storage::disk('googleConsole')->download($fileName);
    $file = $response->send();
```

Comment: Even i am looking to download files from google drive. Could you please share laravel package you are using.